# The difference between "char* variable" and "char *variable" in C

Tags: c

I'm learning C and I'm wondering about the difference between writing `type* variable` and `type *variable`.

Comment: It's a matter of preference, but as the accepted answer says, in `int* myVariable, myVariable2;` it may not be *immediately* obvious that `myVariable2` is `int` and not `int *`.

Comment: For the same reason we *don't* declare arrays as `type[N] variable;` - the `*` is part of the *declarator*, not the type specifier.  Because whitespace is not significant (at least in this case) you can write it either way, but it is always *parsed* as `type (*variable);`.